# Making a command run once every day at 11pm and copy a file(flie1.seq) from one directory(xyz) to other directory(abc)

Tags: linux

I am using the Putty and trying to write linux commands that makes run once every day at 11pm and copy a file(flie1.seq) from one directory(xyz) to other directory(abc), the file in xyz folder has to be a current date (Like the file has to be modified or created today(current date) then it has to copy over or else ignore).
Wondering if someone please help...

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Where are you getting stuck? Keep in mind, specific questions get specific answers.

Comment: Have you produced a command that does what you're after yet? Are you trying to understand how to schedule something to run daily? You're probably interested in cron (and [`crontab`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)), and utilities like [`date`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html). It might be possible to do what you're after in one line, or you might have to write a small script.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I am trying to understand to write the script, so far I am using this command : cp /xyz/file1.seq  /abc/. and this is just copying over the file when i run it command. eventually I am looking for something that runs this at 11pm every night and copy the file which has the current date (like today's date).  I am looking to for nice way to have the syntax that does this please...

Comment: *"eventually I am looking for something that runs this at 11pm every night"*.. did you not read @Attie mentioning ***cron*** ?  First, write a script that does what you want, next.. [use cron](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux) to run it at 11pm every night.

Comment: Try putting together crontab, rsync and mtime

Comment: Thanks for the response everyone, I will try today putting together the scripts..

Answer (score 0):

1- Switch to the user that you want to execute this sequence as.

2- Create a cronjob that will execute your command everyday at 11pm :

```
crontab -e
```

This will open a text editor where you can write your job :

3- Then copy the below snippet and save it :

```
00 23 * * * /bin/cp /xyz/file1.seq /abc/
```

4- Check that the cronjob is set :

```
crontab -l
```

PS: Note that **cp** will flush the timestamps automatically to the current action time : atime, mtime, ctime

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try today putting together the scripts..

Comment: let me know if the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

method using crontab and rsync

```
#m  h   dom mon dow command
00  23  *   *   *   /usr/bin/find /xyz/flie1.seq -daystart -mtime -0 -exec /usr/bin/rsync -az {} /abc/ \;
```

find file "flie1.seq"  in path /xyz/ where

- -daystart = from start of "today"
- -mtime 0 = with modification time today
- -exec rsync = execute rsync

using rsync options -az

- a = keep attributes (except hardlinks)
- z =  compress file data during the transfer

sync to folder /abc/

**rsync** is very convenient and my preferred method as it easily to use if your desination is a remote server.